# Find and replace inside regex result in Excel VB

Tags: regex, excel, vb.net, replace, find

After much frustration and reading documentation I still can't seem to find the way to run a search for a regex pattern and replace characters inside all the matches in the spreadsheet for that pattern.

I have this content in a cell:

```
$test string[0] = "this is a test string."; $another test string[431] = "yet another test string";
```

This is my regex pattern:

```
"\$(.*?)\["
```

outputs:

```
test string, another test string
```

I need to find all the matches and replace the space for a hyphen in order for the output to be:

```
test-string, another-test-string
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The output is: `test-string, another-test-string` and the rest is ignored ? I'm almost sure you'll have to do this in 2 steps.

Comment: Basically I just want to do a find and replace for what I search inside a regex. The complete output would be:

`$test-string[0] = "this is a test string.";
$another-test-string[431] = "yet another test string";`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use positive look-ahead, i.e.:

```
ResultString = Regex.Replace(SubjectString, "(?<=\$.*?) (?=.*?\[)", "-")
```

Comment: That regular expression isn't working for me... am I missing something? Here's a live example:

<img src="http://i.imgur.com/4JrtF6z.png">

Here is the text I entered in the www.regex101.com editor for simple copy-pasting:

**Regular expression**
`(?<=\$.*?) (?=.*?\[)`

**Test string**
`$test string[0] = "testing a string"; $string number 2[231] = "Testing yet another string. More words";`

Played around with it a lot and read even more documentation but still can't solve the problem.

Comment: On your example, the string is in 2 diffent lines. I'll take a look when I'm on my destop.

Comment: Sorry, slowly getting used to this non-wysiwyg editor. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @Haddock-san: If you are going to use it in an Excel VBA code, it won't work due to the lookbehind. And even an indefinite-width lookbehind. This will only work in .NET (and some more few engines). So, in VB.NET, it will work.